# Image view image from imageurl giving exception

Tags: android, bitmap, imageurl

i am using image-URL to represent image in an imageView but my android application is throwing the following exception.
i am using asynchronous task to fetch the image URL and putting it in imageview in onpostexecute() method.

**Mycode**

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ImageView i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            Drawable d;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(logo.get(0)).getContent());
                 i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**logcat exeception**

```
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:190)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at com.example.slideoutmenu.LayerStack$logo.onPostExecute(LayerStack.java:249)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at com.example.slideoutmenu.LayerStack$logo.onPostExecute(LayerStack.java:1)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-05 06:34:25.148: E/AndroidRuntime(1653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how can i show the image from imageurl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPostExecute()` method runs on the UI thread. You should move the following line to the `doInBackground()` method.

`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(logo.get(0)).getContent());`

Comment: i set the width of the image-View as match-parent but the image is not matching the parent

Comment: in your layout xml's imageview tag, add this: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 1):

Try following code which is efficient to use for network task.

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private String data;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage
        // collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        data = params[0];
        try {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(data)
                    .getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to use that class, use following statement.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(img);
task.execute("your image url");
```

Answer (score 0):

> NetworkOnMainThreadException.

You are doing network operation on this method `onPostExecute()` which run on Main thread. Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

Do this network operation in this method `doInBackground()`.